# Not able to Mock HttpContext.Request and pass it to controller

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Hi I have tried a couple of tutorials on the net, but I am not able to mock HttpContext.request.

I have a controller as below:

```
///<param name="reqBody"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpPost("apples")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AppleController() {
var request = HttpContext.Request;
//some lines of code
var (a, b) = await cc.method1(con["para1"], p , q);
//some lines of code
}
```

method1 has an implementation as below:

```
public async Task<(aObject, JToken)> method1(string p, string q, string r) {
//some lines of code
return (a,b)
}
```

I am trying to write a Unit Test for the controller, but I am not able to create a Mock object for HttpContext.Request. Here is what I have written and the error I am getting:

```
[Test]
        public async Task Test()
        {
            
            JToken jTokenObj = JToken.Parse("{}");           
            
            var mockContext = new Mock<HttpContext>();
            var requestMock = new Mock<HttpRequest>();
            mockContext.Setup(d => d.Request).Returns(requestMock.Object);
            
            mockObj.Setup(d => d.method1(It.IsAny<String>(), It.IsAny<String>(), It.IsAny<String>())).ReturnsAsync((a, jTokenObj));

            var result = a.SyncAgency();    
            
            mockObj.Verify(d => d.method1(It.IsAny<String>(), It.IsAny<String>(), It.IsAny<String>()), Times.Once());
           
            Assert.NotNull(result);

        }
```

Error:

```
Moq.MockException : 
Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: d => d.method1(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())
```

Comment: Where are you writing a unit test for the controller? Are you rewriting all the code inside the controller in your test method?

Comment: No I don't wish to rewrite the entire code. I am trying to write the unit test in Test() method.